# Getter uid being called on null in flutter fire

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to concatenate two UID's in order to create a chatroom. One uid is being read from firebase while the other is read from the FirebaseAuth.instance.

The clientUID is being assigned as it should, as I am passing it to another page on a Text widget. However the chatroom is not being created in the firestore tree so I assume this should be because of the instructor uid.

Maybe I am not calling the FirebaseAuth.instance as it should?

Code:

```dart
class ClientiPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'CLIENTI';

  @override
  _ClientiPageState createState() => _ClientiPageState();
}

class _ClientiPageState extends State<ClientiPage> {

  String chatRoomID;
  String clientUID;

  Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

  String instructor;

  void getInstructorId() async {
    instructor = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid;
  }

  void saveChatRoom() {

    getInstructorId();

    DocumentReference chatroomIdRef = db.collection('instructori').document(instructor).collection("chatrooms").document(chatRoomID);

    if (chatroomIdRef == null) {
      db.collection('instructori').document(instructor).collection("chatrooms").document(chatRoomID);
    }  
  }

  void createChatRoom() {
    getInstructorId();
    chatRoomID = clientUID + instructor;

    if(chatRoomID != null) {
      saveChatRoom();

      Navigator.push(
        context, 
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ChatPage(
            chatRoomID: chatRoomID,
            clientUID: clientUID,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: db.collection('clienti').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(      
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                clientUID = snapshot.data.documents[index]["UID"];
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Divider(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                      onTap: createChatRoom,
                      title: new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(
                            snapshot.data.documents[index]["numar_telefon"],
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error

```
The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid
```

Comment: how are u calling this `ClientiPage({Key key, this.instructor})`

Comment: You mean how do I pass the instructor from RegisterState?

Comment: check my answer. I mean the `ClientiPage` is getting called probably something like this: `ClientiPage(instructor: currentUser)`, so what are you passing as a value to the `instructor` property

Answer (score 3):

`instructor` is a instance variable in the class `ClientiPage`, thats why you can access it using the property `widget`. But it seems you are not initializing it correctly.

The `uid` will retrieve the currently logged in user id, you dont have to pass it inside a constructor or from a different screen, therefore you can do the following:

```
 void saveChatRoom() async {
    String userId  = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid;
    DocumentReference chatroomIdRef = db.collection('instructori').document(userId).collection("chatrooms").document(chatRoomID);

    if (chatroomIdRef == null) {
      db.collection('instructori').document(userId).collection("chatrooms").document(chatRoomID);
    }  
  }
```

As long as the user is logged in, you can retrieve the `uid` using the following code `(await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid`. There is no need to pass it from screen to screen.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: Ok, so I tried to implement your answer but now I got more errors, xd. One of them would be that the await expression can only be used in an async function, another that the getter  instance is not defined for FirebaseUser and the other that the FirebaseUser argument type can't be assigned to a string.

Comment: You need to write async here`void saveChatRoom()async {`

Comment: Woops my fault, I updated the answer, please check it. U need to write async when using await and uid is of type String @EneCristianLuis

Comment: FirebaseAuth.instance has nothing to do with how the data is structured. It only retrieves an instance of firebase auth..